# 508 Compliance error - "This SPAN has an id attribute of 'aria-context' and 'aria-selection-event', which is not unique in the same DOM"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, wcag2.0, section508

I'm using the tool Level Access to test my application for 508 violations and which is producing errors on my custom dropdown form.

> This SPAN has an id attribute of 'aria-context', which is not unique
> in the same DOM

and

> This SPAN has an id attribute of 'aria-selection-event', which is not
> unique in the same DOM

Im using react-select for the dropdown and the error I'm getting is from line
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/components/LiveRegion.tsx#L202-L204

it looks like the aria-selection and aria-context spans should only be used during the initial focus, but for some reason stays indefinitely instead of switching to the live region.

[image]

```
<AvSelect
              name="payer"
              labelKey="displayName"
              valueKey="id"
              id={{payers.map(x => x.id)}
              label="Payer"
              placeholder="Choose one ..."
              options={payers}
              index={payers.map(x => x.id)}
              onChange={payer => {
                this.changePayer(payer);
              }}
            />
          )}
```

Here is the screenshot attached for the highlight of the element causing the error and I'm using continuum explorer pro to test the accessibility for the page. Also we are targeting chrome, firefox and safari as main browsers. I see the span tag in the chrome dev tools but I don't see that anywhere in my react code

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the error and your code? For example, most accessibility tools allow you to highlight the element that is causing the error, could you show us a screenshot of that and a more complete (i.e., compiled) HTML code example? Which frameworks are you using? Which browser(s) are you targeting?

Comment: thank you for responding, I have added the details asked in the question above

Comment: Why are you setting `id={{payers.map(x => x.id)}`? HTML attributes are strings. This code does not make a string. Also, the error is about your DOM, so: please show the actual DOM (as found in the "elements" tab), not the component hierarchy. Also remember that posts do not need an "EDIT:" section, you just update your post to have all the details. Also, given that aria roles are their own attribute, find out what's injecting those incredibly wrong span elements. Because if it's not your own code, it's time to run through the [mcve] exercise.

Comment: You need to find where the `<span>` tags with `id="aria-selection-event"` are being injected in your code. Beyond that, I can't suggest anything more without seeing a reproducible code example.